# Sending and receiving encrypted and signed documents in a local client server scenario

Tags: client-server, rsa, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, python-sockets

I want to build a local cilen-server which can transfer a file which will be encrypted by RSA algo and signed and the receiver will decrypt that file and will verify the signature. I found many tutorials on how to build a client server scenario in Python but to send the encrypted file I need to first convert the large file into smaller block and I don't know how to do that and after the receiving the encrypted file how I can setup the receiver that it will automatically decrypt the file using the keys that are exchanged between them at the time of setting up of the connection and verify the signature ? I am hoping to do this without using PyCrypto or any other built in libraries. Is there any tutorial which can help me understand on how to do this in python ? Or any structured way of solving this problem. Looking forward to suggestion. Thank you.